# Changing the background image of div using javascript gives abnormally large image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a simple HTML, JS project, where I need to change the background image of a div, onClick of a button using Javascript.

I have explored and came up with the required code. I can change the image, but the changed image is abnormally large and cannot be seen unless zooming out of the browser. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

This is the jsFiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/john_seen/w751m6or/6/

HTML with Style

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('submit');

if (btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', func);
}

function func() {
  var element = document.getElementById("updateImage");
  element.style.background = "url(https://freepngimg.com/thumb/star/22-star-png-image.png)"
}
```

```css
.solar {
  background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/34/Red_star.svg/1235px-Red_star.svg.png') center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  content: '';
  position: static;
  animation: spin 25s linear infinite;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vw;
}

@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/71/Black.png');
}


/*.shadow { 
             animation: rainbow 2s linear infinite; 
             } */
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Click Meeeeeeee" style="float: left;background-color:#04AA6D;color:white" />

  <div class="middle">
    <h1 style="color:white;">Host name</h1>
    <hr>
    <p style="color:white;">Windows</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="solar" id="updateImage"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="client.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/john_seen/w751m6or/6/

Comment: Well the red star image is over 4x the size of the black square.

Comment: `background-size: cover;` makes the image cover the entire element

Comment: If you update following css value:
 height: 29vw;

Comment: FYI, you can use [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) instead of `var` in both cases here. That's the preferred way to declare constant values in 2023.

Comment: in your javascript just use `backgroundImage` instead of background. When using background you are overriding any of the CSS settings that you already set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`element.style.background` is a shorthand attribute for setting multiple (e.g. backgroundImage, backgroundRepeat, etc.).

It works initially because you define the other attributes after, but when you add it inline, it is overriding all of the other ones as well.

You simply need to do:

```
element.style.backgroundImage = "url(https://freepngimg.com/thumb/star/22-star-png-image.png)"
```

and it will work as expected.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('submit');
    if (btn) {
        btn.addEventListener('click', func);
    }
function func() {

var element = document.getElementById("updateImage");
element.style.backgroundImage = "url(https://freepngimg.com/thumb/star/22-star-png-image.png)"
   

}
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
      <style> 
         .solar { 
            background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/34/Red_star.svg/1235px-Red_star.svg.png')   center center; 
            background-repeat: no-repeat;              
            background-size: cover; 
            content: ''; 
            position: static; 
            animation: spin 25s linear infinite; 
            width: 50vw; 
            height: 50vw; 
         } 
         @keyframes spin { 
             100% { transform: rotate(360deg); } 
         } 
         body { 
            display: flex; 
            align-items: center; 
            justify-content: center; 
            background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/71/Black.png'); 
         } 
         /*.shadow { 
         animation: rainbow 2s linear infinite; 
         } */ 
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div>
         <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Click Meeeeeeee" style="float: left;background-color:#04AA6D;color:white" /> 
         
         <div class="middle">
            <h1 style="color:white;">Host name</h1>
            <hr>
            <p style="color:white;">Windows</p>
         </div>
        
      </div>
      <div  class="solar" id="updateImage">  
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript"  src="client.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```